# Difference between casper.echo and console.log in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Is there any difference between `casper.echo` and `console.log` ?

```
casper.echo('Testing');

console.log('Testing');
```

They both log contents in console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In their most basic form, they are equivalent.

There are a couple of differences, though:

- (only for PhantomJS) Passing multiple objects into `console.log()` like `console.log("s", 1, obj)` is actually equivalent to `console.log("s" + " " + 1 + " " + obj)`. When you try this in SlimerJS, it will only print the first argument and forget about the other ones.
- [`casper.echo()`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/945171f7a380ea3365fd26e0103ba43b51bc40fc/modules/casper.js#L646-L670) is able to colorize the input that you give it. The signature is:

  ```
  Casper.prototype.echo = function echo(text, style, pad) { ... };
  ```

  This is mostly used internally for output coloring like errors and the test harness. You can use [those colors](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/modules/colorizer.js) only if your terminal supports coloring by default:

  ```
  var styles     = {
      'ERROR':     { bg: 'red', fg: 'white', bold: true },
      'INFO':      { fg: 'green', bold: true },
      'TRACE':     { fg: 'green', bold: true },
      'PARAMETER': { fg: 'cyan' },
      'COMMENT':   { fg: 'yellow' },
      'WARNING':   { fg: 'red', bold: true },
      'GREEN_BAR': { fg: 'white', bg: 'green', bold: true },
      'RED_BAR':   { fg: 'white', bg: 'red', bold: true },
      'INFO_BAR':  { bg: 'cyan', fg: 'white', bold: true },
      'WARN_BAR':  { bg: 'yellow', fg: 'white', bold: true },
      'SKIP':      { fg: 'magenta', bold: true },
      'SKIP_BAR':  { bg: 'magenta', fg: 'white', bold: true }
  };
  ```